# How do I activate an unsaved workbook using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, export-to-excel

The goal of my code is to run an online report, copy the data from an exported excel file and paste it back to the main file, and then manipulate the data.

The trouble I'm running into now is copying the data from the exported excel file. The online report exports the excel file as an unsaved "Book1" with one "Sheet1" with the data in it. I cannot seem to activate the exported file so I can copy the sheet.

I've tried

```
Workbooks("Book1").Activate
```

As well as using a for loop to iterate through all open workbooks (there are only 2 open workbooks, but the for loop only loops once - telling me that it isn't looping through the unsaved workbook).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Happy to clarify any questions as well.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the `FindWindow` API helps? Or if there is a way you can set the online report excel file to an object before hand?

Comment: The greater question is, *why would you need to `Activate` a workbook at all?* Either you created the workbook and discarded the returned `Workbook` object instance, or you opened the workbook and discarded the returned `Workbook` object instance, or you copied a sheet into a new workbook and that workbook is `ActiveWorkbook` and all you need to do is `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook` just after copying the sheet, to keep the `Workbook` object instance around. I'm 99% sure you don't need to `Activate` anything.

Comment: It's possible your report is open in a different instance of Excel, so it would be difficult to reach using the regular approaches.  Can you instead Save the report and open it from that location in your current instance of excel?  How are you openeing the report in the first place?